# untar files in Azure Functions App using 7zip

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-function-app

Is it possible to extract files from .tar.gz using Azure Data Factory or Functions App to be ingested by ETL process in ADF?

I tried to use 7zip in Functions Apps, which worked fine to extract a test .tar.gz file uploaded to the Functions App itself but throws an error for files stored in Blob container.

Here's my command in run.ps1 in Functions

```
.\7za.exe x 1.tar.gz
```

#below, the file is a blob in Blob Container - doesn't work

```
.\7za.exe x $InputBlob
```

The error I receive for the command above

> 2020-09-11T16:06:42.721 [Error] ERROR: Program '7za.exe' failed to run: StandardOutputEncoding is only supported when standard output is redirected.At D:\home\site\wwwroot\tools\run.ps1:9 char:1+ .\7za.exe e $InputBlob+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.Exception :Type : System.Management.Automation.ApplicationFailedExceptionErrorRecord :Exception :Type : System.Management.Automation.ParentContainsErrorRecordExceptionMessage : Program '7za.exe' failed to run: StandardOutputEncoding is only supported when standard output is redirected.At D:\home\site\wwwroot\tools\run.ps1:9 char:1+ .\7za.exe e $InputBlob+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.HResult : -2146233087CategoryInfo : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordExceptionFullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailedInvocationInfo :ScriptLineNumber : 9OffsetInLine : 1HistoryId : -1ScriptName : D:\home\site\wwwroot\tools\run.ps1Line : .\7za.exe e $InputBlobPositionMessage : At D:\home\site\wwwroot\tools\run.ps1:9 char:1+ .\7za.exe e $InputBlob+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~PSScriptRoot : D:\home\site\wwwroot\toolsPSCommandPath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unfortunately there is no out-of-box functionality in Azure Data Factory to extract contents from TAR file.

Here is an existing user voice feature request thread, I would encourage you to please up-vote and/or comment on the feature request suggestion to increase the priority of feature implementation.

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/34575520-support-extracting-contents-from-tar-file

But as a workaround you could try using the extensibility features of Azure Data Factory to transform files that aren't supported. Two options include Azure Functions and custom tasks by using Azure Batch (Custom Activity in ADF).

Your [question](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/92973/extract-files-from-targz-files-store-in-blob-conta.html) is already answered on Microsoft Q&A platform.

Comment: page not found :-(